# Creating new record and relationships in one go

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following basic schema:

**players**

```
id
name
```

**profiles**

```
id
player_id
email
```

**subsets**

```
id
profile_id
alias
```

I was under the impression the following operation was possible when creating a new record:

```
Player::create([
    'name' => 'Player 1',
    'profile.email' => 'player1@email.com',
    'profile.subset.alias' => 'Player 1 alias'
]);
```

Since this code doesn't seem to work, is there anyway to save relationships records together with the create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't do this as easy as it looks.

In the docs, all related models are created after the base model is created

```
$profile = new Profile(array('email' => 'player1@email.com','alias'=>'Player 1 alias'));

$player = new Player(array('name'=>'Player 1'));

$player = $post->profile()->save($profile);
```

However , if you really want to do it in one go, you can overwrite the `save()` method in the Player  model :

```
public function save(){
        Database::transaction(function() {
                    $profileModel = new Profile($this->profile);

                    parent::save();

                    $this->profile()->insert($profileModel);

                });
}
```

You will then pass the array to the Player method like :

```
array(
name='Player name',
profile=>array(
         email=>'player1@email.com',
         subset=>array(
           alias=>'Player 1 alias'
          )
);
```

Although this is not a recommended action.

Please read more about how to save the Eloquent models and relationships :

[Tutorial 1](http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel)
[Tutorial 2](http://culttt.com/2013/06/10/laravel-4-eloquent-model-relationships/)

Everywhere is suggested to create the base model first, then the related models.