# Insert related model in laravel 5

Tags: php, orm, model, insert, laravel-5

I use a registration form, that allows to fill data from 2 diferent related models `User` and `UserProfile`, next this data need to be inserted in the database, all the data belongs to a new entry, In other words i have a new `User` and a new `UserProfile` in the database.

I don't know how to insert the `UserProfile` using related models after insert the new `User`.

Here is `User` model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

Here the `UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['bio', 'twitter', 'website', 'birthdate'];

    public function getAgeAttribute(){
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->birthdate)->age;
    }

}
```

And here is what i trying to do, but i can't get it:

```
public function postNew(){
        $params = Request::all();

        $user = new User();
        $user->fill($params);
        $user->save();

        $user->profile->save(new UserProfile($params)); //line 47
    }
```

When i tried to run `postNew()` method, laravel give me this error:

```
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 47:
Call to a member function save() on null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving related records in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228694/saving-related-records-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Use $user->profile() ->save(new UserProfile($params));