# Laravel insert FOREIGN KEY in Form Request method

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my application some tables are relational and I need to insert `FOREIGN KEY` to the table as User id. I don't have any problem with creating a new instance from the model and then use the `save()` method. However I would like to use the `Form Request` method to create and update records.

I get this error, but I don't know how to solve it;

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a >child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`epaypro`.`merchand_web_service`, >CONSTRAINT `merchand_web_service_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) >REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `merchand_web_service` >(`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2015-11-29 11:31:54, 2015-11-29 11:31:54))

This is my model:

```
namespace app;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Morilog\Jalali\jDate;

class Merchant extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'merchand_web_service';
    protected $fillable = ['customer_key', 'company_name', 'company_logo'];

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

`store` method on Controller:

```
public function store(StoreMerchantWebServiceRequest $request)
{
    Merchant::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```

`StoreMerchantWebServiceRequest` class:

```
class StoreMerchantWebServiceRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public function forbiddenResponse()
    {
        return Response::make(trans('message.permission_denied'), 403);
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'agent_company_name' => 'required',
            'agent_company_logo' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png|max:300',
        ];
    }
}
```

My Test (in controller):

```
public function store(StoreMerchantWebServiceRequest $request)
{
    $order = Merchant::create($request->all());
    $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $order->save();
    return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228694/saving-related-records-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty simple way to deal with this situation is in the `store` method in your controller:

```
public function store(StoreMerchantWebServiceRequest $request)
{
    $merchantData = $request->all();
    $merchantData['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    Merchant::create($merchantData);
    return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```