# How do I bind multiple models to a form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

How do I bind multiple models to a form? For example, I have an order and order details section on a form and I want to bind a separate model to the order details fields..

Comment: Can't you call the other controller method in the controller where the form submits. ?, as you can make your actions conditional but you cannot have multiple actions at once..

Comment: Is it separate model or related to the order?

Comment: It's related to the order.

Comment: The following may be related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183394/creating-new-record-and-relationships-in-one-go

Comment: you can try it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38839672/2652524

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up a little on relationships. You can relate two models and then when you post your form to your controller, you can process it then.

Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Hope it helps.