# Form model binding laravel 5.1 for multiple models

Tags: laravel

I want Form model binding for multiple objects in laracollective's Form package?
Something as following?

`Form::model([$user,$vendors], array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id)))`

Where can I request this feature?

Comment: Short answer: you must merge the models yourself and send it as 1 (which is easily possible if you just care about properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using [Laravel-Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html), Unfortunately you cant do something like that. instead you can try something like this :

**UPDATE**

you can query all your model in your controller and combine them like this :

```
      $user = User::where('id',$user_id)->get();
      $vendor = Vendor::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();

      //merge two model
      $user = $user->merge($vendor);

      // return $user;
      return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'))
          ->withTitle('Edit user');
```

and in your form call them like this :

```
{!! Form::model($user[1], ['route' => ['admin.users.update', $user],'method'=>'PUT']) !!}

    @include('admin.users._formEdit')

    <div>
      {!! Form::submit('Save user', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**_formEdit.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('first_name', 'First Name : ') !!}
  {!! Form::text('user[first_name]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name : ') !!}
  {!! Form::text('user[last_name]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
  {!! Form::label('email', 'Email : ') !!}
  {!! Form::email('user[email]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
  {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
  {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
  {!! Form::label('vendor_name', 'vendor_name') !!}
  {!! Form::text('vendor_name', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

**OR ANOTHER SOLUTION**

1. create relation between model of your User and Vendor (one-to-one or one-to-many) example

User :

```
public function vendor(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Vendor','user_id');
}
```

Vendor:

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id);
}
```

2. Build your response query like this :
   `$user = Vendor::with('user')->find($user_id);`
3. and then in your view template :

`{!! Form::model($user, ...) !!}
  Vendor: {!! Form::text('vendor_name') !!}
  User: {{ Form::text('user[username]') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}`

Comment: I liked your another solution, I did this using the first approach. Next time I will use your another solution where applicable.

Comment: I only use this for two model, I haven't tried it using 3 or more different model, maybe the update solutions will work for that. thanks I'm glad I could help